# Make the image inside of a div change to another image on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I using jQuery make the image inside of a div change to another image on mouse over?  I have a div that holds inside of it an image, a header, and some text.  I want to make the image change on mouse over.

Also the template I use uses a lot of jquery but the files are all over the place.  Where should I put the function?

[image: Here is an Image of the DIV]

EDIT: Here's the code I have so far:

**CSS:**

```
#tour {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding:56px 0 47px
}

#tour #link {
    height:auto;
    width:200px; /* 140px + 60px */
    float:left;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-left:10px;   

}

#tour #link:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

#tour img {
    /* Float the image to the left of text */
    width:50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right:10px;
    height:auto;
}

#tour h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    display:block;
    width:140px;
    float:left;
}

#tour p, #tour p.last {
    display:table-row;
    width:140px;
    alignment-baseline:baseline;
    /* Custom added */
    color: #333;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 140px;   
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tour"> 
   <div id="link" onclick="location.href='#';"  >               
      <img src="images/icn1.png" alt="" />
      <h2>Pitch</h2>
      <p>Present your ideas in a manner that will leave your customers in amazement.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do... is it to make the image clickable? make it hoverable? make the div clickable/hoverable? What?

Comment: 2. can you describe/show the file structure for the JS files?

Comment: I'm confused. You say in your title that you want the image to be clickable. But your question is about swapping out images on hover. If it's on hover that you're seeking, do you want the images to change when the mouse enters the div or the image?

Comment: whoa.  Sorry guys. I'll put up more info right now. Didn't expect such a quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div#imageContainer').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).children('img').attr('src','../newImage.png');
});
```

That'll do it. Doesn't matter where you put the code, as long as it's within the `$(document).load(function(){...});`

NOTE: this is using the latest jQuery 1.7.1 `.on()` function which is new to this version. Same thing can be accomplished with `.bind()`

Update for comments:

If you want to keep this function in a separate file, you can wrap it in a function

```
function imageSwap(){
    $('div#imageContainer').on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).children('img').attr('src','../newImage.png');
    });
}
```

And then just call the `imageSwap()` function from within the document load.

Also, if you want to use this on multiple divs with different images, you can do one of two things. Either A) name your images something like `img1_over.png` and `img1.png`, in which case you can modify the code as such:

```
$('div#imageContainer').on('mouseover', function(){
    var img = $(this).children('img');
    img.attr('src', img.attr('src').replace('.png', '_over.png'));
});
```

Or you can store the image path in a data attribute on the image themselves. In your HTML you would add the hover image to a data attribute like so:

```
<img src="../cool_img.png" data-hover="../ever_cooler_image.png" />
```

And your code would look like this:

```
$('div#imageContainer').on('mouseover', function(){
    var img = $(this).children('img');
    img.attr('src', img.data('hover'));
});
```

Comment: Cool.  So my question is: - I have a couple of these divs. and each one links to a different page and has a different picture.  How can i put that information in the HTML?

Comment: And the load function is in another js file.  Do I have to put my code there?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing this in [CSS with a sprite background image](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites), but if you must do it in jQuery...

```
$(function() {
  var div = $("#yourDiv");
  var img = div.find("img:first");
  var orig = img.attr("src");
  div.hover(
    function() {
      img.attr("src", "ImageOver.png");
    },
    function() {
      img.attr("src", orig);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: yea I think you're right.  I should do it with CSS but I have multiple images.  Is that still a good idea?

Comment: @FreeLancer There is no limit to the number of images you can put into one sprite. Please read the article I linked to, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're so-inclined, you could also do this without javascript by replacing your image with an anchor element, styling it, with CSS, like this...

```
a.imageLink {
    background: url('path/to/image.png') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: [width-of-image]px;
    height: [height-of-image]px;
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

and then swapping out the background image with the `:hover` pseudoclass:

```
a.imageLink:hover {
    background-image: url('path/to/hover_image.png');
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea. But since I have multiple images that need to be swapped I want to go with an HTML alternative.  Or which is more closer to convention?

Comment: You can do this with multiple images by specifying a different class for each unique primary/hover image combination. In this case, it would probably be a good idea to create a set of uniform **sprite images** (images that contain each of the different states for a dynamic image at different positions in the same image, not unlike a filmstrip), and use the `background-position`property to slide the appropriate part of he background image into view. Then, you can define one class that handles hovering of all the pertinent images identically, and use additonal classes for each unique image.

Comment: Agreed.  As a general rule of thumb, it's better to use CSS for stuff like this as much as possible because it will always perform better than JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do this with CSS.

```
#img:hover {background: green;}
```

If you must use jQuery use .hover().

```
$("#img").hover(function (e) {
    $(e.target).css('background', 'purple');
},
function (e) {
    $(e.target).css('background', '');
});
```